# This app would like to: Have offline access and No overload for method 'Fetch' takes '2' arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

login via google plus using ASPSnippets.GoogleAPI , it always ask "This app would like to: Have offline access"...

to resolve this, i found

http://aspforums.net/Threads/121490/Solved-ASPSnippetsGoogleAPI-This-app-would-like-to-Have-offline-access/

as told on this link i updated the  API,

after that it gots the error

"No overload for method 'Fetch' takes '2' arguments" on

```
string json = GoogleConnect.Fetch("me", code);
```

in this  line.... how to fix this....

or else please give me a solution for remove This app would like to: Have offline access...

Comment: I thinks depends on GoogleAPI dll version, have you downloaded the latest and asked in the developer forum?

Comment: ya i downloaded the latest one ....